# How do I add date to attachment name?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

My VBA code downloads attachments from emails to my local drive. I would like to rename the attachments to include the date. The date should be the day before the email was received.

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "\\gbhxxxx\Groups\Shared\EBS\Post Go-Live\Auto MT940 download Test"

For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments

    ' Criteria to save .940 files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, "UKAutoMT940") Then
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code below to append the date BEFORE the display file name.  We do this by using DATEADD and adding -1 days to the recieved date and FORMATting the datetime value into a date value with "-"s instead of "/"s.

If you're looking to add it AFTER the filename but before the extension, we'll need to parse to filename.

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "\\gbhxxxx\Groups\Shared\EBS\Post Go-Live\Auto MT940 download Test"


    For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .940 files only

    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, "UKAutoMT940") Then

       object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(DateAdd("d", -1, item.ReceivedTime), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```